# Save data to sql

Tags: android, sql, database, string, search

My goal is:

To be able to stock many text strings in a database,and at every string there will be a 1 or a 0.

If a button is pressed,then the text from TextViewx is saved in a database with a 0.

Also:
If button2 is pressed,search the database like this: If the first string in database that appears has a 0,ignore it and go to the next one,do this untill you find a string with a 1. If the string has a 1,then make the TextView1 in main.xml have the string with the 1.

I got some code from the android sdk website,and yes everything I edited might be wrong,so please help me achieve what I said above:

```
   public class texttest extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String TEXT_TABLE_NAME = "Thestrings";
private static final String DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TEXT_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            THE_TEXT + " TEXT, " +
            0 or 1 + " TEXT);";

DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, texttest, null, 2);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(texttest_TABLE_CREATE);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Can you please clean up your question (formatting, grammar, spelling) and describe what you're trying to do a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use spaces in Table names, also use a plural form, as a table is collection of more than one records.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a general question, so the best I can do is give you a general answer. It sounds to me like you're still a little confused about using SQL and databases in general. Why don't you go through this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) which introduces you to the basic concepts of sql and databases? If you're unsure of how to do things when a button is clicked, then read about [input events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html#Events).